# how to start netbeans with parameters

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, config, text-editor

Questions:

1) i'm using netbeans 8.0.2 on windows and i wanted to change the font size of the package explorer tree view to make it bigger, i read this from the netbeans wiki page (http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFontSize) and it says that i can run netbeans with parameters like this `netbeans --fontsize 14` but when i try to do that on my cmd in windows it don't find the keyword netbeans. how can i run the netbeans ide like they mention in the page.

2) in the page it says that i need to do this everytime if i want to use a different font size and if i want to change it permantly i need to modify a .conf file but the netbeans.conf file that i find in the path that they mention is only a plain text file with all the lines comented, the comented lines says that if i want to change something i need to go to this path `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\` but in this path there are to many folders called css and i dont know what should i edit.

Answer (score 1):

In the config file are a few lines that aren't commented
look at line 46 there is the following statement:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

This is the line mentioned in the wiki text. Add here simple `--fontsize 14` within the ""

I hope that I could help you!
BTW: Opening the file with Notepad++ or an other editor than windows standard gives more overview!

Comment: i tried with this `netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all  fontsize 14" ` but when i change it like that my netbeans wouldn't open i also tried like this --fontsize 14 but my netbeans wouldn't open

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your NetBeans shortcut icon -> go to the "target" field (to the end) -> paste/type there " --fontsize 14" -> press Ok.
Every time you will use this shortcut, NetBeans will start with the font-size you need.

Have you tried it? - it works for me.

Comment: i right clicked my netbeans desktop ico but i dont see that target option

Comment: @stackUser2000

Then go to your NetBeans installation directory (mine is C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\bin). If you have two exe files there (64 and 32 bit) chose one you need (64bit if your OS is 64bit). Right-click it and select "Create shortcut". You may move it to your desktop or any other folder (and rename it i you wish) - Then you should have the target option on right click the shortcut.